# Multidimensional Variable with Different index length in Pyomo or Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, pyomo

I want to solve an optimization problem in Python. I am trying to define a variable x_{g,h} where the index g belongs to the set G and the index h belongs to the set H(g), i.e., the set of indices h varies for different indices g. Is there any way to define variable x with these indices in Pyomo or Gurobi-Python?

In Pyomo, I tried to define it in a loop, like

```
for g in p.keys():
    for h in range(0,p.rop[g].npairs,1):
        model.x_gen_h = Var(g,h,within=NonNegativeReals)
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

I appreciate any help or comment!

Comment: one of the G or H(g) is actually just an int, and not what you think they are. can you share full traceback?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Paritosh. I revised the question to show the loop exactly. I think the error is irrelevant. This must be something related to how we define variables in Pyomo. Indeed, my question is: How can we do list comprehension while defining a variable in Pyomo or Gurobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is in defining the indexing set used to index the variable. Pyomo does not support looping over individual indices and adding them to a Var one at a time. You should use some clever Python code to build up the whole indexing set. For example, you can use something like this to filter out the indices you want:

```
m = ConcreteModel()

m.g = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])

h = {1:['a','b'], 2:['b','c'], 3:['c','d']}
m.h_all = Set(initialize=set(sum(h.values(),[]))) # Extract unique h values

# Initialize set to be entire cross product of g and h and then filter desired values
m.hg = Set(initialize=m.g*m.h_all, filter=lambda m,g,hi:hi in h[g])
m.x = Var(m.hg, within=NonNegativeReals)
```

An even better alternative would be:

```
h = {1:['a','b'], 2:['b','c'], 3:['c','d']}
m.hg = Set(initialize=list((i,j) for i in h.keys() for j in h[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at some example models cited from Pyomo documentation: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_examples.html.

You shouldn't need to use a `for` loop to construct the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I could not find the answer to my question there. In other words, my question is: can we do list comprehension when defining variables? for example, is there any way to implement this:

model.x = Var( G.keys() , H[g] for g in G.keys() )

where G.keys() is an index list and H[g] is an index list for each g. In all the examples provided in the Pyomo textbook or on the Pyomo website, the the two index lists are independent.

Comment: For variables, there is dubious support for jagged sets (in that I don't racall if any of the developers currently use that capability). You can play tricks with `Var(dense=False)` if you are careful, but since unused variables (those that do not appear in constraints) are not passed to most solvers, you should be safe defining over the independent sets, unless there is a real memory limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be initialized with multiple `Set` parameters resulting in variables that are indexed with elements from the Cartesian product of these sets.
If you need contiguous integer indices, the `RangeSet` can be used instead of `Set`

The same `Set` or `RangeSet` set may appear multiple times as a parameter in the declaration of a set of variables, this is nicely explained [here](https://fneum.github.io/data-science-for-esm/08-workshop-pyomo.html)